# Burp Suite Professional Error Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: security, burp

I am completely new to burp suit and dvwa as well, I have one task into my plate to execute, that is security testing, I have invested today entire day to collect data and watch videos and to apply the same to my assigned task, which is not successful yet so I finally take a step to ask you guys for help.  I hope someone will help out on my below queries and issues which I am facing now, Thanks in advance.

I have installed DVWA on my windows 7 machine, updated properly in a config file, not from the command prompt, and run Apache and SQL properly in XAMPP control panel but when I try to execute it's redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8080/dvwa/setup.php And when I try to click on Create/Reset database I got this error 
"Could not connect to the MySQL service.
Please check the config file."
"Your database user is root, if you are using MariaDB, this will not work, please read the README.md file." 
Please note: I didn't use "MariaDB"

One more thing I am facing an issue here, If I run BurpSuit then it is not opening http://127.0.0.1:8080/dvwa/ getting an error: "Burp Suite Professional Error Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:80" last 8080 it is taking 80 only.

Please help me out how to resolve this.﻿

Comment: The Burp problem may be caused by the Burp port clashing with the DVWA port. Run Burp on a different port (such as 8081) an try again.